# Math enthusiast wants to learn math

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education, book-recommendation

I'm an english major with a vivid interest in mathematics,I've read and enjoyed What Is Mathematics? by Courant and Robbins (does this count as some background?),and I've decided to begin a serious study of mathematics, I've looked up many books and judged them by the reviews on ams ,maa and zbmath,and narrowed it down to the following:

Calculus/Analysis: Mathematical Analysis I,II By Zorich(what are  the exact prerequisites for this one?)  ,Problems in Mathematical Analysis by Boris Demidovich .

Complex analysis: Visual complex analysis by Needham.

Abstract/linear algebra: A Course in Algebra by E. B. Vinberg,Algebra by Michael Artin.

Geometry: Modern Geometric Structures And Fields by Novikov and taimanov.

Topology:O.Ya. Viro, O.A. Ivanov, Kharlamov and Netsvetaev, Elementary Topology: Textbook in Problems.

Differential Equations: the books by V. I. Arnold.

Methods in physics:Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics  by V. I. Arnold ,A Course in Mathematics for Students of Physics by Bamberg and Sternberg.

Do you have any comments on the choice of books ? any better suggestions? any suggestions for other subjects ?

Comment: First go through one book from beginning to end. As much as you can. 

Then it might create a new interest. Focus on that book. And repeat this cycle.

Comment: You might have difficulty with some of the definitions and notation.  Much of this is covered in a typical calculus class.  Perhaps having a basic calculus text next to you as you read the Calculus/Analysis text you have chosen might be a good idea.  You can find them at a used book store pretty easily.

Comment: A good way to start is [Proofs and fundamentals](http://www.amazon.com/Proofs-Fundamentals-Course-Abstract-Mathematics/dp/0817641114), by Ethan D. Bloch.

Comment: Point is that basic math is usually covered in basic university courses and I most used the notes of my professors. Avoid topology as a subject in the beginning, unless you are really interested by it. For algebra I recommend "Basic algebra 1" by "Nathan Jacobson".

Comment: Number theory can be a very fun way to get started in math. You might want to check out some of the popular introductory number theory books.

Comment: I've bought venkov number theory's book ,is that good?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Venkov.  I've heard good things about Hardy and Wright, and I think [A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Friendly-Introduction-Number-Edition-Featured/dp/0321816196/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1407803941&sr=8-7&keywords=number+theory) by Silverman looks good (quite expensive though).  I think the book Calculus by Spivak is another good book for getting started in math.

Comment: I know of Venkov 's book,I've seen it recommended by Vladimir Arnold,so it must be good.

Comment: You might be rushing things a bit. If you haven't done mathematics for a while, it might be a good idea to first review high school algebra and trigonometry -- really master it if you haven't already. Then try first-year algebra and calculus (for beginners). My guess is you are probably not ready for an intensive proof-oriented course in analysis or abstract algebra. You really have to master the computational aspects of mathematics as a base to draw on before you start to do complicated proofs.

Answer (score 1):

A good book for a first look at analysis is Bartle's real analysis. A very good introductory linear algebra text is Linear Algebra Done Right, by Axler. Another good linear algebra text is finite dimensional vector spaces by Halmos. For basic topology, nothing beats Munkres. Another good abstract algebra text is Basic Algebra 1 by Jacobson; another is Hungerford. You should also learn some number theory. For number theory, I'd say Davenport's Elementry number theory or Strayers.

Comment: Thanks! do they contain some physical applications?

Comment: Not really. They might have some, but it would be minor. Linear algebra books usually talk about some applications. Abstract algebra books do sometimes as well. But, you can't really look too much at applications in an introduction. You'll only be able to look at the most elementary applications

Comment: Do you any comment on zorich's book on analysis?

Comment: No I don't, sorry. I have never even heard of that book. Honestly, just look at a few different analysis texts online (there are ways to find them), and select one that you find easy to read.